# How do I set CMD+TAB to show Mission Control

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, mission-control, finder

I dislike the `cmd + tab` app switcher, since I can't switch between apps for my needs.

I prefer Mission Control for this.

Is it possible to re-map `cmd + tab` to show Mission Control on macOS?

Comment: Can you describe how you are unable to switch between apps "for your needs" with Cmd Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Better Touch Tool (BTT)](https://folivora.ai/).

1. Install BTT and open the Configuration window

You can always click the BTT icon in your menubar and select "Configuration" to open):

*Menubar icon:*

[image: Screenshot of menubar icon]

2. Using the dropdown menu at the top, select Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Click the `+` at the bottom and press your shortcut `cmd + tab`. (You can see it be recorded in the right-most panel.)

You have now added a »trigger« for `cmd + tab`

[image: Screenshot of BTT configuration window]

4. Click the `+` under »Assign First Action to Selected Trigger«
5. Search for `Mission Control` and select the option called just `Mission Control`

[image: Screenshot with search for using Mission Control as an action]

6. Press `cmd + tab` and Mission Control should be activated. Enjoy!